# How do u add lives and a counter to display the lives

Tags: python

I want to add lives to and a counter displaying how many lives I have left

I tried adding a counter using range but it prints all the no like 1, 2, 3 I just need it to display 1 number that represents lives u have left

```
num = random.randint(1,10);
print(num)
guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))

if(guess == num):
    print("correct")


else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Comment: can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a for loop:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,10)
for i in range(3):
    guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    if(guess == num):
        print("correct")
        break
    else:
        print("incorrect")
    print(2 - i, 'tries left')
```

Comment: How would u end the game after u have hit 3 tries and make the game completely stop

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while loop for this. Each guess a counter would be decreased by one. The loop would run while lives > 0.

```py
num = random.randint(1,10);
print(num)

lives = 3
while lives > 0:
    guess = int(input('Guess a number: '))

    if(guess == num):
        print("correct")
        break

    else:
        print("incorrect")
        print("%s lives left." % lives-1)
        lives -= 1
```